# Batch script to read/write data using COM port

Tags: bash, batch-file

I need to write a batch script that can read and write to a COM port (in my case, COM1).

I know that I can send data to a COM port using

```
echo hello > COM1
```

And I can read data coming in to a text file using

```
type COM1 > sample.txt
```

I'd like to be constantly capturing the data coming into the COM port into a text file and be able to send commands to the COM port depending on what data was just read on the COM port. Is there a way to do this in a batch script?

Would it be easier/better to do it in a bash script? How would I do it in bash?

**EDIT:**
The data I wish to read is the output of the boot of a system to an UEFI shell. Then, when it gets there, enter some commands and capture the output of those commands. Then, boot an OS (capturing the output of the boot), enter some more commands to the Linux shell and capture the output of them. It does not contain an exact number of characters.

If a bash script is the only answer, that is ok. I can work with that. I am currently running version 4.1.10(4) of bash in Windows 7 using cygwin.

Comment: Uh, the batch file syntax you are mentioning seems to come from Windows/DOS. `bash` is mainly a shell for Unix-like systems - unless you are using something along the lines of Cygwin. *Which* operating system are you using? Do you actually *have* bash installed?

Comment: I am using Windows. And yes, I do have bash installed.

Comment: Which version of bash, and just to be clear, would a bash script only answer be acceptable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Playing around with a few different things with batch scripts leads me to believe nothing is going to work in with a batch script and the standard Windows command line tools. `set /P` returns immediately when reading from `COM1`, and something like `type COM1` will copy the serial data in large chunks line by line.

I had better luck using Cygwin bash. Here's a simple script that receives lines from `COM1` and echoes them back. It exits when it receives a line starting with "quit". You can test it out by using a terminal emulator on the other end of the serial link or just using statements like `echo quit > COM1`.

```
CR="$(echo -e '\r')"
exec 4<> /dev/com1

cat <&4 | while :
do
    IFS="$CR" read -r line 
    case "$line" in
    quit*)
        echo "goodbye$CR" >&4
        break
        ;;
    *)
        echo "recieved line: $line"
        echo "recieved line: $line$CR" >&4
        ;;
    esac
done
```

The `CR` variable holds a carriage return character which in this example is used to strip it off the input lines and used to terminate lines with CR LF when outputting them over the serial line. Depending how exactly your BIOS behaves you may or may not need to do this in your own script.

The `exec 4<> /dev/com1` line is crucial. This opens the COM port once for both reading and writing. Windows only allows a COM port to be open once, so if this wasn't done it wouldn't be possible to read and write to the COM port. The `4` means that is assigned to file descriptor 4 and the `exec` statement keeps it open for the rest of the script.

The `cat <&4 |` part is also important. Unfortunately there seems to be a bug in Cygwin bash where it will try to rewind the file descriptor if it reads past the end of a line. This works for files, but it doesn't for serial ports so data gets lost. To workaround this problem the script reads from a pipe instead, which bash is smart enough to not try to rewind.

The reason for setting `IFS="$CR"` is to strip off the carriage return at the end of a line as mentioned before, and to not strip off anything while reading. The `read` command uses the IFS string to break up the input line into words. You may be able to use this to your advantage and set it to a different value to make it easier to parse the BIOS output.

The rest of the details are pretty straightforward. The `-r` option for `read` causes it not to treat `\` characters specially. Depending on what sort of line endings your BIOS expects you have three different ways you can write your echo statements:

```
echo "Both CR and LF line ending$CR" >&4
echo -n "CR only line ending$CR" >&4
echo "LF only line ending" >&4
```

One thing this script doesn't do it set the COM port parameters like baud rate and flow control. This is probably best done using the normal `MODE COM1` command. Cygwin has an equivalent `stty` command, but it doesn't appear to support all the parameters.

Another entirely different option is to use Expect. If you find that it's hard to get bash to parse and respond appropriately to your BIOS's output then you might consider using that instead. This sort of thing is what its designed for, though there's a bit of learning curve if you're not already familiar with TCL. It's available as a standard Cygwin package.

Comment: Thanks! This seemed to print out each line fairly well, except it would occasionally lose the first couple letters in a line. I also couldn't ever get it to exit when it got to a line starting with "Shell>*". I modified your example to instead print to a file. Inside the while loop, I looked at the current last line of the file and used an if statement to look for "Shell>". I could then echo commands to the COM port. If I break, it sometimes stops the cat command (I can see it through Windows Task Manager), but it never exits the script, even if I put an exit command after the loop. Help?

Comment: Yah, there's a little problem with my example I didn't fully realize until now. `cat` will only stop running when it fails to write to the pipe. That will only happen when the while loop exits and `cat` has something to write to the pipe. So if the while loop exits when the other end has nothing more to send `cat` will hang around forever. Before exiting the loop trying sending a dummy command to the other end that will cause it to send something back.

Comment: Also, I sent in a bug report to Cygwin maintainers about the rewinding   bug. They've fixed it in the current development version of Cygwin, so eventually when that becomes part of a release it'll be possible remove the `cat` command altogether.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time in this write-up! The "<>" was very helpful for me on a test environment that uses Cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to read data from the serial port is *not*:

```
type COM1 > sample.txt
```

nor:

```
copy COM1 sample.txt
```

It would be if that data would have a standard EndOfFile mark, like a Ctrl-Z character.

If that data comes in *lines* that ends in CR+LF or just CR characters, then the standard way to read them would be:

```
set /P "var=" < COM1
```

If that data have *not* a delimiter, like CR or CR+LF, then you must specify the exact format of such data:

- Do you want to read records of a fixed number of characters?
- Do you want to read characters until a certain one appear? Which one?
- May the input data contain control characters? Which ones?
- Any other format of the input data?

**EDIT**: *Reply to the comments*

When `set /P` command is executed with redirected input, it does *not* wait for data. In this case, it returns immediately and the variable is not changed.

We may try to wait for the next character received from the serial port and *then* execute the `set /P` command; this way, the `set /P` should correctly read an input line terminated in CR or CR+LF that does not contain control characters.

This is the code:

```
set "key="
for /F "delims=" %%K in ('xcopy /W "%~F0" "%~F0" ^< COM1 2^> NUL') do (
   if not defined key set "key=%%K"
)
set /P "line=" < COM1
set "line=%key:~-1%%line%"
echo Line read from COM1: "%line%"
```

Try it and report the result. Sorry, I can not try input read from COM1 in my computer.

Comment: You tried that? It doesn't work for me under Windows 7. It returns immediately leaving `var` unchanged.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Just locks up in `xcopy`. I don't think your idea would work anyways. `xcopy` wouldn't just wait for input, it would also consume at least one character of the input. It wouldn't echo it back to standard output either.