# A batch script that reads and appends a PuTTy log in real time

Tags: batch-file, timestamp, append, putty

I am wondering if this may be beyond the capabilities of batch scripts.  I need a script that constantly moniters a PuTTy serial log file.  Every time a 0x04 signal occurs, a tab, timestamp and new line needs to be appended.

I am sure the script will have to read in the putty log (.txt) and output to a new text file but I am not sure if batch scripts can read constant input.

Thank you for anyone that helps!

Comment: What are the manifestations of the `0x04 signal`? If it's written to a log file then it's possible to write such batch script. If it's a keystroke (Ctrl-D) which is only pressed by the user and isn't stored anywhere then you're out of luck.

Comment: It is a unique signal used to end every message.  The idea is to timestamp every message that arrives in real time for debugging later on.  0x04 is not used in any other part of the message.

Comment: I would like to stream COM3 and place a time stamp and a carriage return every time the 0x04 is encountered.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25333898/3959875).