# Oneliner to get / read the serial buffer and return the value to the standard output

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, serial-port, serial-communication

I'm pretty sure this question should have been asked before, but I can't find the answer. I want to read the content of the serial buffer and echo it to the console / terminal / standard output.

---

**Requirements:**

1. CMD / batch commands, no powershell
2. it must be a oneliner
3. preferably using `copy`, `type`, `more` and other simple commands like these.

---

**Attempts**:

**A.** First assuming I have set the parameters:

```
mode COM7:9600,N,8,1,P
```

Then from [here](https://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/356229-reading-serial-port-command-line.html#post2967739) I have tried

```
copy COM7 CON
```

and

```
type COM7
```

but it just doesn't return anything.

**B.** Also answers on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329129/batch-script-to-read-write-data-using-com-port) are for copying the content of the serial buffer to a file, but I need to print it to the terminal or at least store it in a variable.

**C.** From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25333898/4999991) I also tried:

```
set /P "var=" < COM7 & echo %var%
```

but it just returns `%var%` obviously not reading the buffer. Adding the `cmd /V:ON /C` at the beginning of the above command also did not help.

**D.** from [this page](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_redirection.php)

```
copy COM7 > CON
```

and

```
copy COM7 2>&1
```

and

```
copy COM7 | more
```

all led to the error:

> Access is denied.
>           0 file(s) copied.

---

I would appreciate if you could help me find the right command. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't test on my computer. Anyway, variant A. seems reasonable to me, variant C. as well; variant D. however seems to be useless as there is no copy destination given (when copying files, `copy` uses the original file name together with the current directory as the default dest., but when a device like `com#` is given, it might just mirror the data back, like `copy con` mirrors back to `con`). Nevertheless, all these commands need to receive some end marker to terminate (end-of-file, ASCII 26, *Ctrl+Z*, and for `set /P`, end-of-line too; perhaps a null byte might work too?)...

Comment: @aschipfl so if I have understood you correctly, A and C are the right direction. Would you be kind to elaborate?

Comment: As I said, I can't test it, so it's a bit difficult. I don't know where the `Access denied.` message should come from (by the way, does this only relate to attempt D.?). Anyway, variant A. is of correct syntax at least. Variant C. cannot work as written, since `echo %var%` returns the value of `var` present *before* the whole line executes (sorry, I forgot this before); you could use `set /P "var=" < COM7 & call echo %^var%`, or enable [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) by running `cmd` with the `/V` option. But all relies on terminated text data (end-of-file, etc.).

Comment: N. B.: You could also try `more < com7`...

Comment: @aschipfl awsome `more < com7` worked almost fine. It just prints a couple of extra empty lines for some reason.

Comment: @aschipfl I just tested this on a different computer and it doesn't work! when running `more < COM7` it is still stuck and does not print anything to the terminal!

Comment: @Foad Does the other computer have com7 enabled? if not, find out which com it uses.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard yes it does. I'm using com0com to create pairs of virtual serial ports and I have named them similarly for my own ease.